# Rails can not load spreadsheet gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spreadsheet

I have already run `gem install spreadsheet` in my Rails project,but it still shows the error:

```
no such file to load -- spreadsheet
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit your `Gemfile` to include:

```
gem 'spreadsheet'
```

Then you'll need to run `bundle install` to get that injected into the `Gemfile.lock` file.